# postgresql: show the client (not server) time zone

Tags: postgresql

In Postgresql:

```
SHOW TIME ZONE;
```

... produces a result like `Europe/Zurich` or `America/New_York` according to the **server time zone**. Is there any equivalent command to show the **client** time zone (or perhaps client session time zone) in the same format, so that it can be passed to things like the `timezone()` function?

I have a server in `Pacific/Auckland` zone being passed records with `TIMESTAMP` values from a `Australia/Sydney` site, and I need that latter time zone so I can convert in certain circumstances using `timezone( local_client_session_timezone, time_from_server )`. So far I can only specify the value of `local_client_session_timezone` in that context from an external source. How do I get it from my database session?

Comment: If customers are using a web or desktop app to access information from PostgreSQL, I'd create a way for them to specify a timezone they'd like to see, store that in the database and convert data to that timezone on the fly.

Comment: We don't have customers per se. We may have someone move our equipment, or be forced to replace a PC, and change or set the time zone in Windows as a result... but that's as far as it goes. The rest of the process of getting that Windows locale through to the client session is somewhat opaque to me...

Comment: How are users accessing the database?

Comment: Our software accesses the DB via an API (Poco libraries). It is a standalone data acquisition system. I can make it work if I prescribe the time zone... I'd just prefer to know how I can reliably program the software to get the client time zone by itself in case the equipment is moved/changed, as has happened in the past.

Comment: Postgres server can’t find client’s time, to my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

The `timezone` parameter is initialized from the server setting, but if you are writing a time zone aware application, each client session should override the value with `SET` to determine the session time zone.

Then you don't have to explicitly convert timestamps: simply use the data type `timestamp with time zone`. Every session inserts timestamps in its local time zone, and the timestamp is automatically converted to the session time zone of any client that queries the data. So everybody sees the same timestamp in their local time zone.

Answer (score 0):

If you set PGTZ environment variable, then libpq-based clients like `psql`, `psycopg2` and `DBD::Pg` will automatically send that content over as the timezone in the start up packet.  Other connection libraries will have other practices, which will hopefully be documented.